# Handling foreign keys in asp.net

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I'm working on my membership website that's connected to a database. All the tables are already created in the database. However, I have a problem with handling foreign keys. I actually don't know how to do it...

I use VS 2012 for Web

This is the registration page that a member fills out when they want to join the club. In the member table I have a couple of foreign keys that need to be handled: addressID, membershipID, emergencyContactEmail and clubID.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
public partial class Default2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(IsPostBack)
        {
            SqlConnection regConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionstring"].ConnectionString);
            regConn.Open();
            string check = "select count(*) from member where memberEmail ='" + emailTB.Text + "'";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(check, regConn);

            int i = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
            if (i == 1)
            {
                Response.Write("User already exists");
            }
                regConn.Close();
        }
    }
    protected void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Guid addressGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
            Guid medicalGuid = Guid.NewGuid();
            Guid membershipGuid = Guid.NewGuid();

            SqlConnection regConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Data Source=student5;Initial Catalog=FeelGoodDatabase;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=*******"].ConnectionString);
            regConn.Open();
            string insertMember = "insert into member (memberEmail, firstName, surname, dateOfBirth, password, contactNumber) values(@email, @firstName, @surname, @dob, @password, @phone)";
            string insertAddress = "insert into address (addressID, lineOne, lineTwo, town, county) values (@addressID, @lineOne, @lineTwo, @town, @county)";
            string insertEmergency = "insert into emergencyContact (emergencyContactEmail, emergencyContactName, emergencyContactSurname, emergencyContactNumber) values (@emEmail, @emName, @emSurname, @emPhone)";
            string insertMedical = "insert into medicalInfo(medicalInfoID, physicalHealthInfo) values (@medicalInfoID, @healthInfo)";
            string insertMembership = "insert into membership(membershipID, membershipType, paymentOption, membershipPrice) values (@memID, @memType, @payOption, @amount)";
            string selectedMembership = this.RadioButtonList1.SelectedItem.Text;
            string selectedPayOption = this.RadioButtonList2.SelectedItem.Text;

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertMember, regConn);
            SqlCommand cmdAddress = new SqlCommand(insertAddress, regConn);
            SqlCommand cmdEmergency = new SqlCommand(insertEmergency, regConn);
            SqlCommand cmdMedical = new SqlCommand(insertMedical, regConn);
            SqlCommand cmdMembership = new SqlCommand(insertMembership, regConn);

            cmdAddress.Parameters.AddWithValue("@addressID", addressGuid.ToString());
            cmdMedical.Parameters.AddWithValue("@medicalInfoID", medicalGuid.ToString());
            cmdMembership.Parameters.AddWithValue("@memID", membershipGuid.ToString());

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", emailTB.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", firstNameTB.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@surname", surnameTB.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", dobTB.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", passwordTB.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phone", phoneTB.Text);
            cmdAddress.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lineOne", lineOneTB.Text);
            cmdAddress.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lineTwo", lineTwoTB.Text);
            cmdAddress.Parameters.AddWithValue("@town", townTB.Text);
            cmdAddress.Parameters.AddWithValue("@county", emailTB.Text);
            cmdEmergency.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emEmail", emEmailTB.Text);
            cmdEmergency.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emName", emnameTB.Text);
            cmdEmergency.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emSurname", emSurnameTB.Text);
            cmdEmergency.Parameters.AddWithValue("@emPhone", emPhoneTB.Text);
            cmdMedical.Parameters.AddWithValue("@healthInfo", medicalTB.Text);
            cmdMembership.Parameters.AddWithValue("@memType", selectedMembership);
            cmdMembership.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paymentOption", selectedPayOption);
            cmdMembership.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amount", amountTB.Text);   
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmdAddress.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmdEmergency.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmdMedical.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmdMembership.ExecuteNonQuery();

            Response.Redirect("MemberPage.aspx");
            regConn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Response.Write("Sign up not successful");
        }
    }
}
```

Also, when I run this code, I get an error message stating: Object reference not set to an instance of an object which happens on this line:

```
SqlConnection regConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Data Source=student5;Initial Catalog=FeelGoodDatabase;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=********"].ConnectionString);
```

Do you have any idea how to fix this?
Thanks.

Comment: It's essentially an undefined variable.  Forget all this database stuff and focus on that.

Comment: ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings is an array, which probably has an easy key that relates to elements of the ConnectionString section of your web.config. Putting the entire connectionstring as an index of an array is probably not a good idea:)

Comment: Please see the example at [ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.connectionstrings%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for how to use it.

Comment: The sql string code in Page_Load is crazy-vulnerable to sql injection attacks. It's practically begging to get hacked. Use query parameters, as you do elsewhere in the code. Also, don't use the 'sa' account in your programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use Connection string key instead of using whole connection string in ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings. Asp.Net not able to find the key in web.config and throws the Object reference.

```
SqlConnection regConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Student5DB"].ConnectionString);
```

And make sure this key define in Web.Config

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Student5DB" connectionString="Data Source=student5;Initial Catalog=FeelGoodDatabase;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=********" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```